# Load code into HTML using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, external

I know it's possible, and I've looked at numerous examples. And I'm afraid I already know the answer to my question, but perhaps I'm missing something.
I was thinking that this does not work because I am running this code locally, and not on a server.

In my head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#test").load("test.html");
        } );
</script>
```

In my body tag:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

My external code (inside 'test.html")

```
<div>This is what you should be seeing!</div>
```

Shouldn't this work?
Additionally, in my external html document, do I need set it up with all the extra tags, so that the document would look like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>

<div>This is what you should be seeing!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

All my files are in the same directory.

Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the extra html tags in test.html, it should just have the div. Also, look use a debugging tool like Firebug to see if a request is being made.

Comment: I do know the script runs, as I've tested that with an alert(), but I'll double check with Firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your code should work on webserver! Please let me know if you are doing it from you desktop.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").load("./test.html"); //  also try /test.html
    } );
</script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this essentially is identical to my code, and has the same effect i.e none.

Comment: @Jonannes to be honest you code is working you must have some erors with your webserver ... and alternately you can try ajax to load

Comment: I'm not running this on a web server, as I stated in my question. I believe this to be the issue.

Comment: @Johannes are your files in localwebserver or just normal folder?

Comment: also check your firebug console (under `console` tab, you should see a `GET`  request and in `Net`  tab You will also be able to see under `all` tabl) if it is seen then your code is working`

Comment: Firebug says `$('#test').load('test.html');` runs just fine, but nothing appears. I'll assume it has to do with it being local?

Comment: @Johannes that the problem you got. I myself am not quite in that position to explain this, but you know know that you normal folder does not handle request (like web - server), and function `load` sends `GET` request so this is not working. try it in you localhost if you are having any problem then let us know

Comment: P.S. it sends request to server, not on filesystem

Answer (score 1):

Simple

```
$.get('test.html', function(data) {
    $('#test').html(data);
});
```

The .load() have a different function, to bind event handlers on load event

UPDATE:

To add the data insted replace try the append

```
$('body').append(data)
```

Comment: I replaced my current script with this, and it didn't change a thing. Was I not supposed to replace anything but add it instead somewhere?

Comment: Ah, no, I DO want to replace the content. I was wondering if I should replace my script with the one you've provided, or add onto my script. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: But could you load an external file using `.append` ? I noticed you can put formatted html code in -- but I was wondering if you could put a file in there instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use a optional selector after the URL to only put the `<body`>'s content (or something else) into the target:

```
   // will load the contents of test.html's body-element into #test  
   $("#test").load("test.html body");
```